# Python Resample timestamp String Data to weekly data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have string data generated at each timestamp. I want to convert it to weekly data.
My code:

```
df = 
index                   data
2019-10-01 08:43:54    A
2019-10-01 08:45:24    B
2019-10-02 08:49:42    C
2019-10-02 09:01:04    A
2019-10-03 09:07:04    A
2019-10-10 08:43:54    A
2019-10-10 08:45:24    B
2019-10-12 08:49:42    C
2019-10-12 09:01:04    B
2019-10-13 09:07:04    A
```

**Objective**: Convert above data into weekly data. Weekly averaged data should include the number of times that a particular string repeated
**Desired answer**:

```
wdf =                              # Weekly dataframe
index          A    B   C
2019-10-01     3    1   1
2019-10-08     2    2   1
```

I have **two questions**:
Q1. My solution approach described below is the best one?
Q2. is there a better solution?

**My approach**: Create additional columns in original dataframe and assign 1 or 0 if the string present in the `data' column

```
new_cols = df['data'].unique().tolist()
df[new_cols] = " "
df[new_cols] = df[new_cols].isin() # I think this is not the right code. 
df =             # This is expected solution from above code
index                   data    A     B     C
2019-10-01 08:43:54    A        1     0     0
2019-10-01 08:45:24    B        0     1     0
2019-10-02 08:49:42    C        0     0     1
2019-10-02 09:01:04    A        1     0     0
2019-10-03 09:07:04    A        1     0     0
2019-10-10 08:43:54    A        1     0     0
2019-10-10 08:45:24    B        0     1     0
2019-10-12 08:49:42    C        0     0     1
2019-10-12 09:01:04    B        0     1     0
2019-10-13 09:07:04    A        1     0     0
wdf = df[new_cols]
wdf['datetime'] = wdf.index
wdf = wdf.resamle('W',on='datetime').sum()
wdf =                              # Weekly dataframe
index          A    B   C
2019-10-01     3    1   1
2019-10-08     2    2   1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use `pd.pivot_table`. Assuming you have this dataframe with datetime index:

```
                    data
index                   
2019-10-01 08:43:54    A
2019-10-01 08:45:24    B
2019-10-02 08:49:42    C
2019-10-02 09:01:04    A
2019-10-03 09:07:04    A
2019-10-10 08:43:54    A
2019-10-10 08:45:24    B
2019-10-12 08:49:42    C
2019-10-12 09:01:04    B
2019-10-13 09:07:04    A
```

Then:

```py
print(
    df.pivot_table(
        index=pd.Grouper(freq="7D"),
        columns="data",
        aggfunc="size",
    )
)
```

Prints:

```
data        A  B  C
index              
2019-10-01  3  1  1
2019-10-08  2  2  1
```

---

If `"index"` is just ordinary column:

```
print(
    df.pivot_table(
        index=pd.Grouper(key="index", freq="7D"),
        columns="data",
        aggfunc="size",
    )
)
```

Comment: Just wow. This is a crazy answer. I am thinking of three loops and long lengthy code. I started doing it. But yours is just one line solution. One last stupid question: how do you know that using `pivot_table` can be solved? I am new to Python.

Comment: @Mainland Actually, your operation is just pivoting the table + additional resampling. I've looked at doumentation for [`pd.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html#pandas-pivot-table) and found that `index=` is accepting `pd.Grouper`. The rest is easy.

Comment: For instance, I have two columns `data1`, `data2` string data. Both columns have unique strings data. Using above `pivot_table`, can I convert just like above?

Comment: @Mainland Generally yes, you can pass list of Groupers and/or column names to `index=`, `column=` parameters

Comment: I just tried using two columns. The column names are overlapping. I am seeing more column names than when I run with single column names. Here is my code `wdf = wdf.pivot_table(
        index=pd.Grouper(freq="7D"),
        columns=["rcb1_maxcol","rcb2_maxcol"],
        aggfunc="size")` So, doing individually on two columns and then concating two solutions is good approach? Or I simply have to correct this solution?

Comment: @Mainland Yes, doing it separately and then concatenating is ok. As long as the performance is enough and the code is readable :)

Answer (score 2):

Considering `index` as column name.
(If not, reset the index, `df = df.reset_index()`)

```
df['index'] = pd.to_datetime(df['index'])
df.groupby(['data', pd.Grouper(key='index', 
            freq='W')]).data.count().unstack(-2)
```

**Output**

```
data    A   B   C
index           
2019-10-06  3   1   1
2019-10-13  2   2   1
```

If we don't need multi index:

```
df.groupby(['data', pd.Grouper(key='index', 
          freq='W')]).data.count().unstack(-2).rename_axis(None,axis="columns").reset_index()
```

**Output**

```
    index       A   B   C
0   2019-10-06  3   1   1
1   2019-10-13  2   2   1
```

Comment: Interesting one-line solution. I got an error `KeyError: 'The grouper name timestamp is not found`. My index name is `timestamp`

Comment: Ahh, This is because pandas is considering column named 'index' as index axis.
It's always good to not name the column as index, this may cause ambiguity.
This is the solution considering 'index' as column name. If it's an index(row axis) then you might have to reset index.